# Do we have a way to fail github action that runs JS if it has exception from YAML file?

Tags: javascript, npm, github-actions

I have a github action that runs a JS file,
the js file can raise some exceptions,currently, I make it fail if we have any exception using ** core package ** .

My question is: do we have another way to make it fail from `YAML` file.
if yes what is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: What kind of exception would it be?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski it will be an array of strings

Comment: Please show some YAML and ideally create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)